# Extract multiple pattern from string pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Create new column with the extracted middle and last strings from a column within a dataset.

**Data**

```
Status             ID
Ok                 hello_dd           
Ok                 hello_aa_now       
No                 standard_cc        
no                 standard_ee_not
```

**Desired**

```
Status             ID                        type
Ok                 hello_dd                  dd     
Ok                 hello_aa_now              aa
No                 standard_cc               cc
no                 standard_ee_not           ee
```

**Doing**

I am able to extract the last string, however, still researching how to extract the middle string.

```
df['type'] = df['ID'].str.strip('_').str[-1]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the string after the first `_`:

```
df['type'] = df['ID'].str.extract(r'_([^_]+)')
```

With [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['type'] = df['ID'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

output:

```
  Status               ID type
0     Ok         hello_dd   dd
1     Ok     hello_aa_now   aa
2     No      standard_cc   cc
3     no  standard_ee_not   ee
```